# has.js : how to fix Cannot convert undefined or null to object

Tags: javascript, webpack, babeljs, yarnpkg, core-js

After a yarn upgrade, my console throw me the error `Cannot convert undefined or null to object` from a file `:at ./node_modules/core-js/internals/has.js.module.exports (has.js:4)`
I tried `yarn cache clean` and `yarn install` but still the error

Is anyone having any idea how to fix that ?

Comment: Try removing node_modules and `yarn installl` or `npm install`

Comment: thx for your help but it didn't work, still have the error

Comment: Are you using babel-runtime? There is open issue with workaround on github: https://github.com/zloirock/core-js/issues/705